# just add destructor that do nothing can cause compile error (around std::move), why?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rule-of-zero

While I was learning `std::move`, I found a strange issue.

If I add only a destructor that do nothing to a perfect program, I will get a compile error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class M {
public:
  int database = 0;

  M &operator=(M &&other) {
    this->database = other.database;
    other.database = 0;
    return *this;
  }

  M(M &&other) { *this = std::move(other); }

  M(M &m) = default;
  M() = default;
  ~M() { /* free db */ }
};

class B {
public:
  M shouldMove;

  //~B(){}   //<---  ## Adding this line will cause compile error. ##
};

int main() {
  B b;
  B b2 = std::move(b); //## error at this line if the above line is added
  return 0;
}
```

Live code: https://ideone.com/UTR9ob

The error is  `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'B&' from an rvalue of type 'std::remove_reference<B&>::type {aka B}'`.

### **Question:**

- (1) Which rules of C++ syntax enforce that?  In other words, what does the error mean?
- (2) If I want to add destructor that do almost nothing (e.g. only print debug log) to `B`, do I really have to follow **the rule-of-five** instead?   If no, how to make it compile? Following the rule of five just because of that is too tedious and dirty in my opinion.

I think **the rule of zero** is just a good practice.

However, from this example, it seems to me that it is a hard rule that if  violated, I will get compile error.

Comment: If you add a destructor then you *have* to define some how other special functions if they are going to be used. They can `default` for example `B(B const&) = default` or `B(B&&) = default`.

Comment: @alfC You mean the answer for the 2nd question is "Yes"?

Comment: I think if you write a destructor then you have to *at least* follow the rule of three. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three . If you know that you can write a move constructor then you have to follow the rule-of-5.

Comment: I think the most sane recommendation is delegate all the "non-zero" classes to a base class or an implementation member that only has the special member functions (rule-of-3, rule-of-5, etc). Some times you simply really want a smart pointer to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implicitly-declared move constructor is only present if a class does not have a user-declared destructor. Therefore the answer to 2. is YES.

The answer to 1. is that this is hard rule and can be found in 12.8, paragraph 9 of the standard:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>
> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
> - the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
>
> [ Note: When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that
>   otherwise would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor. — end note ]

The best way of getting this to run,is by using something like a smart pointer, i.e., a base class or member that does define all five special members (and very little else) so that you don't have to. In this case, an integer handle equivalent to `std::unique_pointer` should work well. However, keep in mind that databases, like files, can have errors while closing, so standard non-throwing destructor semantics don't cover all cases.

Comment: I was just adding it while you wrote the comment :)

Comment: Nice job, Joe.  That is what I looked for, for a long time.  Thank.

Comment: Good answer, however is the answer to the second question really YES? he can follow the rule of three, no? Specially if he doesn't need a move constructor/assignment.

Comment: @alfC As the question is explicitly about `std::move` I'd doubt that having the object copied in the line `B b2 = std::move(b);` line would match the intent.

Comment: @alfC After a fast test, the rule of three is not enough. (It can compile but will just copy.)  https://ideone.com/eOawAX  It supports Joe's answer.

Comment: @javaLover, I think that is because you have a move constructor already. I am confused by your example, you can have a class with destr/copyconstr/copyassign happily. Note that also `  M(M &m) = default;` is something strange to have and doesn't participate in any of the rules (I think.)

Comment: @javaLover Yes, if a copy constructor is present your value will be copied, not moved. But it will compile. Remember, `std::move` *does not* move!